# what is the corresponding sql data type for abap DF16_DEC data type?

Tags: sql, types, abap, sap-data-dictionary

I am trying to map abap data type to SQL data type, but I don't know to which data type in SQL should I map. I am trying to map these following data type:

- DF16_DEC: 8 byte Decimal floating point number stored in BCD format.
- DF16_RAW: 8 byte Decimal floating point number stored in binary format.
- DF34_DEC: 16 byte Decimal floating point number stored in BCD format.
- DF34_RAW: 16 byte Decimal floating point number stored in binary format.

Can anyone tell me to which SQL data type should I map these types?

Comment: In which database software?

Answer (score 3):

That is answered rather extensively in the [on-line documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenddic_decimal_floating_point.htm). Be aware that your question does not make much sense within the ABAP environment because `DFnn_[DEC|RAW]` already are dictionary types that can be mapped to runtime types `decfloatnn`. Generally speaking, `DFnn_DEC` is mapped to a `DEC` type and `DFnn_RAW` is mapped to a `RAW` type. Mapping these types to the underlying database types might depend on the DBMS product used though.

Comment: bad link: use [this one](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenddic_decimal_floating_point.htm)

Comment: @vwegert https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60526765/folder-creation-on-downloaded-multiple-files-email-or-pdf-from-saptcode-va03